# "The sale goes on through the 16th" Why is this correct?

Tags: prepositions

> Q: "The sale goes on [...] the 16th."
>
> a. through (correct)
>
> b. toward
>
> c. into
>
> d. for

I really don't understand why *through* is the answer.

Context note: This is a practice question from [TOEIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOEIC).

Comment: Even with the word *through*, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 8):

ODO on [through](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/through#through__14) sense 4:

> [preposition] *North American* up to and including (a particular point in an ordered sequence):
>   *they will be in London from March 24 through May 7*

None of the others make sense at all [although this use of *through* is not used in British English].

Comment: I would understand *The sale is on for the 16th*, though it's rather informal. Mixing singular and plural doesn't make the original any easier to understand.

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, *is on for* is OK (if informal). *Goes on for* doesn't make sense though. It's not a good sentence at all.

Comment: @TimLymington I would understand *The sale is on for the 16th* to mean that it is *only* on *on* the 16th.

Comment: As @AndrewLeach says, *through* is not used in this sense in BrE, and I think many Brits would not understand it. Hence, it hardly seems appropriate for 'International English'! One could say "goes on until", altho' "is on until" would be more common in BrE.

Comment: @TrevorD: Yes, and *is on through the 16th* in America would mean 'until the 16th'. There's no way of telling which is intended.

Comment: Please note that *is* is **not** included in the sentence as given by the OP. The verb is ***goes***.

Comment: @TrevorD It's not the TOIE.  What about International Communication with AmE speakers?  (I'm pratciting up for my TOEIN - Test of English for International Nitpickping, of course.)

Comment: I realise that *is* was not in the question. I was just commenting on what (similar) phrases might be used in the UK.

Comment: @Andrew, this is the first time I vote an answer two times, here and on ELU, yup!

Comment: @hunter2 But it was "*English* for *International* Communication", and my emphasis was on the *International* part. My point was that I'm sure that the apparently correct answer was not suitable for *International* Communication if it's primarily an AmE phrase, whereas I'm sure that there are other phrases that could have been chosen and that would be equally acceptable for both AmE & BrE, and therefore more suitable for *International* communication. (And I'm also quite good at 'nitpicking' in general!)

Comment: I'm shocked that this isn't used in British English. It never occurred to me that this isn't ubiquitous.

Comment: There's a difference between "through" and "until" in AmE. "Through" means the time period is inclusive: that is, the sale is still on on the 16th. "Until" is ambiguous.

Comment: @TrevorD: If there's one thing I've learned by frequenting ELL and ELU, it's that many practice questions for these exams are riddled with problems. I'm convinced many of these practice questions we see on SE come from test prep materials published by third-party companies who are out to make money, and the quality of each individual question isn't always first-rate.

Comment: @TrevorD As a practical matter, I know what you mean. As an impractical matter, your emphasis was on (an assumed) *Inat Eng* and mine was on (the stated) *Inat Comm*; someone in a (non-US) call center serving US customers (one of many realistic examples) is engaging in 'Inat Comm' in AmE. An argument could be made otherwise, but I agree that the goal of the test probably is what you infer - Inat Eng, suitable for communication with AmE, BrE, and others. // (your at-tag didn't work, presumably b/c I hadn't logged into ELL yet, and your comment was after the migration)

Comment: @PeterShor As regards BrE, I agree with you in theory, but in practice "until" would always be inclusive (in this type of context), as would "to"* (e.g. "from 12th to 16th"). But, if I understand you correctly, you're saying that **in AmE** "until" would be ambiguous? So do we have any unambiguous phrases in common for this usage?!

Comment: @hunter2 Good example - I hadn't thought of that. Of course, we also get lots of foreign 'international' call centres - the other day I asked an operator where she's located and it was The Philippines! I wonder if the same call centres/staff serve UK & US?

Comment: @TrevorD: For the sentence "The sale goes on until ...", even in AmE I think "until" would probably be inclusive. But a sentence like "the rainy weather will continue until Thursday" might mean that it will stop raining Wednesday night; while "the rainy weather will continue through Thursday" makes it quite clear that Friday will be the first day without rain.

Comment: @TrevorD Also non-E countries in 'the Americas', where AmE is likely to be the most common Eng, just due to proximity. // Phillipines is a pretty big place for call centers these days, I'm sure they serve both/all markets; FWIW, their English-speaking is, (ahem) 'historically tied to' the US.

Comment: @TrevorD: A sale which lasts "until" the 16th will end at some time on the 16th.  A sale which lasts "through" the 16th will continue until the last possible moment on the 16th.  If a store which is open from 9am to 9pm has weekly specials that go into effect at 3pm, a sale that lasts "until" the 16th may end at 3pm on the 16th, while a sale that lasts "through" the 16th would effectively end at 9pm on the 16th.